# How to compute this partial derivative

Tags: partial-derivative

I'm trying to understand a paper about the mathematics behind the Word2Vec model. I have come across an expression that I'm sure it's obvious but I have not been able to quite understand on my own. These are the facts we have:

$$
y = f(u)=\sigma(u)= \frac{1}{1+e^{-u}}
$$

where $\sigma$ it's the sigmoid function with the following properties:

$$
\sigma(-x)=1-\sigma(x), \,\,\,\,\,\,\, \frac{d\sigma(x)}{dx}=\sigma(x)\sigma(-x)
$$

Taking that into consideration, I need to compute $\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$, and the paper says the following:

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = y(1-y)
$$

Can anyone explain the steps there, please? [This is the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.2738.pdf) I'm referring to, in case I have missed something else needed. Thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed to use the properties you stated without proving them? (Or for that matter, have you proven them already?) Because they trivially imply $\sigma^\prime=\sigma(1-\sigma)$.

Comment: Yeah, I can use them without proving them. Using the $\sigma'$ notation I have already seen it, the $d$ notation got me a little bit confused. Thanks!